# Setting up OpenID Connect for a private domain?

Tags: login, openid

I am interested in setting up OpenID to comment on various blogs with a URL linking to my private domain. Previously such services were provided through OpenID 2.0 and one could use Google profiles to make it work as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541526/delegate-openid-to-google-not-google-apps

Now that Google migrated to OpenID Connect how can I obtain the same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. OpenID Connect *is not* OpenID – it's actually an OAuth2-based protocol.

Existing OpenID clients cannot talk to a Connect provider, and you might have noticed that OAuth & Connect clients don't actually have an option to input your own provider, only to select from pre-configured ones.

For the two websites that still support OpenID, you'll have to choose a different IdP.

(At the time of writing, I know of Stack Exchange's [own](https://openid.stackexchange.com/) OpenID service, as well as the slightly buggy Launchpad. It seems VeriSign's PIP will be discontinued in Sep 2016 – no longer an option.)